# How to prove lexicographic ordering is reflexive given only "less than" condition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

I'm reading about partial ordering, I know by definition it means reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive. But the examples in my textbook that confused me are of the form:

> There is a ordering/relation, and the "less than" of this relation is defined as follow [...] Now by adding equality to this ordering it becomes a partial ordering.

But how can I prove that the ordering/relation is reflexive only given its "less than" condition? e.g.

[image: lexi1]

My try:

Say this ordering relation is $R$ and it's denoted by $\prec$. For any $a\in R,$ since $a\not\prec a$ because neither $(a_1, a_2,\dots,a_t)\prec$ itself nor $m\lt n$ (since $m=n$). Then I stuck at this step.

--

Am I on the correct path proving reflexive from antisymmetric? Or reflexive is defined on the set, so this property don't have to be proved?

--

another one that similar but I also don't know how to prove:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, any of these *"less than"* relations is **NOT** a partial ordering — exactly because it's not reflexive. They are antisymmetric and transitive, though — which, of course, shouldn't be taken for granted, but should be verified for each example. But then we can define another *"less than or equal to"* relation, which will be a partial ordering. In other words, each of the examples above talks about two different (but closely related, no pun intended) relations — *"less than"* and *"less than or equal to"*.

I can agree that this text is a bit sloppy at times not to distinguish them clearly enough. For example, in the end of your first screenshot, the phrase

> The verification that this is a partial ordering is left as Exercise 38 …

appears to be talking about the *"less than"* relation, for which it isn't true — of course, the question is actually about the *"less than or equal to"* version. (Maybe it is made clear in the exercise?)

In other words, you can think of this as a two-step definition.

1. First, a certain relation $\prec$ is defined. It's pretty much an ordering, being antisymmetric and transitive. But technically speaking it's not a partial ordering because it's not reflexive.
2. Then the actual **lexicographic ordering** $\preccurlyeq$ is defined as follows: $a\preccurlyeq b$ if and only if either $a\prec b$ or $a=b$. Using properties of $\prec$, we can prove that it is a partial ordering. Proving the reflexivity part is vacuous, since it's part of the definition.

**P.S.** And no, you can't prove reflexive from antisymmetric, as these are two different properties, and neither implies the other.

Comment: So reflexive-ness of lexicographic ordering is to fit our understanding of the world? So it's in the definition? Math aside, thank you!